# Relaying Party application not working when shifted to another machine

Tags: asp.net, azure, acs

I have a ASP.NET Relaying Party application that is configured to authenticate through ACS. The Web Site runs fine on my local host. The problem is that when i copy the website to another machine, it doesn't work and throws the following exception:

### **Server Error in '/Website' Application.

Access is denied. 
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.**

Another interesting point is that when running on the new machine the URL of the website has changed,for example on my machine it was "http://localhost/Website/" while on the new machine it is "http://localhost:51975/Website/".

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Is this an ACS v2 configuration?

You should change the Realm and the Return Address in the Relying Party application to match the URL of your development website (including the port).